# Taylor series of exponential function inequality example

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Assume $d$ positive integer and $\epsilon$ small positive real. How one infers that
$$(1-\epsilon)^d\leq e^{-\epsilon d}$$
using the Taylor expansion of exponential function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from $1 - \epsilon \le e^{-\epsilon}$, which you can verify using calculus (show $f(x)=e^x - x - 1$ is nonnegative by computing its minimum).

Comment: (+1) In fact, one need not use calculus to show that $e^x\ge 1+x$.  See [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263).